# get data of how results have been found in Amazon Cloudsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

as we use cloudsearch to find our documents and data, we have this issue that some of the data that are returned back to us, we have to know that how they've been found.

I know that we can specify which fields to search for them, but is there any way that amazon gives us a hint or some information that how the returned data has been found. on which fields it exists?

this can be really really useful information for us and affects the way we show data to our users.

I know amazon provides highlighting service,  but highlights change results, we don't want to change results or values, we just want to use this knowledge for backend purposes.